# How do I open a embedded video from youtube in a new HTML template. I am using flask

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, flask, youtube

I am making a web app and what I wish to do is that I want to open the video that has been embedded from youtube in a new HTML template. Also, I wish to capture the video id or maybe anything that could help me identify the video so that I can update my recommendations based on the recent clicked video.

So for doing that, I thought I could replace all the embed videos with their thumbnails and on-click I can render the new template but I don't know how to send the data from one HTML template to the other in flask in this case particularly the youtube embed link corresponding to that thumbnail. Sorry for any mistakes.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedding the video can be easily done with bootstrap.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/abcdefghijk"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

For redirecting from html. You can use the following:

> 1.) Create a new route in python file and redirect to 2nd html file.
>
> 2.) Create a link in 1st html to redirect. href to route(or url_for('somelink') if you are using 'url_for').
>
> 3.) User click the link in 1st html and will be redirected to 2nd html.

**Find the Sample code below:**

*Python File:*

```
@app.route("/linktosecondhtml")
def linktosecondhtml():
    return render_template('linktosecondhtml.html')
```

*First HTML file :*

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/abcdefghijk"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="{{ url_for('linktosecondhtml') }}">Link to Second Page</a>
```

Even if you want to pass something in second html page. It can be done with 'url_for'. Or if you need to perform some special task in second html, you can do it in python file route function.

Comment: Thanks!! I am new to flask and had no clue that we can use url_for for passing data, that really helped me.